# Not able to change is_active status od a user in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on webapp where the admin of a domain has the task to register other users of the same domain as his. Not able to authorize the users when I click on authorize.

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
class AuthUserCheckbox(forms.Form):

    choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[], widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
        super(AuthUserCheckbox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choice'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=[(i.id, i.email)
                                                          for i in User.objects.filter(is_active=False, email__icontains=user_email)])
```

Here is my **views.py**:

```
@login_required
def authorize_final(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        authorize_users = AuthUserCheckbox(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if authorize_users.is_valid():
            email_list = authorize_users.cleaned_data.get('choice[]')
            for i in email_list:
                if i.is_active == False:
                    i.is_active = True
                    return HttpResponse('<h3>Authorized successfully</h1>')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('<h3>Authorization failed</h3>')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('<h3>Post request error</h3>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with the code.

First, the error you are getting is due to syntactical issue. Also you are treating `User.objects.all()` as ordinary list, where you don't need to. You can directly use the [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) like the following code:

```
    user_email = self.user.email.split('@')[1]
    super(AuthUserCheckbox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['choice'].choices = [(i.id, i.email) for i in User.objects.filter(is_active=False, email__icontains=user_email)])
```

Here, I am directly querying if the email domain exists in User's email and also checking if the user is active or node.

Second, in the view you can access the choices from form's [cleaned data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) like this:

```
authorize_users = AuthUserCheckbox(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
if authorize_users.is_valid():
    email_list = authorize_users.cleaned_data.get('choice')
    User.objects.filter(pk__in=email_list).update(active=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 authorize_users = AuthUserCheckbox(data=request.POST, user=request.user.username)
```

Comment: can you write and explain me the view for it ? I want to make it work in the manner that, when one or multiple users are selected in the checkbox, they are authorized. I am having a hard time figuring out the view for it